# Why does scala sortWith function is taking Predicate as input

Tags: scala, sorting

I am from java background and learning scala. I am able to understand sorted and sortBy functionality but not able to fully grab sortWith function. I have read that sortWith function will take one function argument which will have custom comparision logic. In java output of a comparision logic is negative (i.e. this object is lesser than that object), zero(this and that objects are same) or positive(this object is greater than that object). 
But here in scala comparision logic is expected to be boolean. I am not sure how to represent less than, greater than and equal condition in boolean.

Comment: If you look at examples, it expects a `<` function to be passed. You can get `a > b := b < a`, and `a == b := !(a < b) & !(b < a)` from it.

Comment: The function is supposed to say if the first value should come before of the second or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to represent all the `lt`, `equals` and `gt` cases. Sorting can be accomplished only by checking whether the first one precedes the second.

Method definition:

```
def sortWith(lt: (A, A) => Boolean): C
```

My opinion is that this approach is less confusing than having to return -1, 0 or 1.

Comment: Thanks @Feyyaz for this explanation. I am able to sort the list having custom object with **sortWith** in both ascending and descending manner based on different attribute.

Comment: Here is the sample code I have executed on SCALA REPL.  
`scala> case class Order(orderId:Int, orderStatus:String)  
scala> var orderList = List(Order(1,"Shipped"), Order(2,"Delivered"), Order(3, "InProgress"))  
scala> orderList.sortWith((x,y) => x.orderStatus.compareToIgnoreCase(y.orderStatus) < 0)  
res115: List[Order] = List(Order(2,Delivered), Order(3,InProgress), Order(1,Shipped))  
scala> orderList.sortWith((x,y) => x.orderStatus.compareToIgnoreCase(y.orderStatus) > 0)  
res116: List[Order] = List(Order(1,Shipped), Order(3,InProgress), Order(2,Delivered))`